# Searching for a name in a text file

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have a text file that I'm searching for the first name "dhillon", the text file contains alot of data but I'm trying to find the first part of the text file which has the name "dhillon".

I tried `grep dhillon name.txt` and it returns all the `dhillon` names, but some `dhillon` names are last names. I need the first line of text which is the first name to be `dhillon` only.

Comment: Welcome to U&L!  What have you tried?   How did it not work as expected or intended?  Have you read the manual page for such tools as `grep`, `awk`, or  `sed`

Comment: I tried grep dhillon name.txt and it returns all the dhillon names, but some dhillon names are last names. I need the first line of text which is the first name to be dhillon only

Comment: please advise bro

Comment: @RocStream share the text file here

Comment: [edit] your question to explain what you just said in that (first) comment,  and to give an example of what your name.txt file looks like.

Comment: name name number number hieght

Comment: thas a example ive been trying grep ^"dhillon" myfile.txt

Comment: i feel like its something like that

Comment: @RocStream, please **[click here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/471742/edit)** (the [edit] link is always available under your question/answer you  posted) to add details  into the body of your question and avoid answering in comments to response for the comments asked for clarification.

Comment: Does your file have data in columns? Or can you share some sample data in your question?

Comment: no data in columns

Comment: How are the fields delimited? tabs, spaces, commas?

Comment: its just a text file with names and random information

Comment: You said the file was layed out like this, right? "name name number number hieght" Is that right? If there is a space between name and name then the "fields" are space(or tab) delimited.

Comment: Without a detailed description and / or sample data, providing a solution is nearly impossible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try: "nl name.txt | grep dhillon"

This will add line numbers to the front of each line, and the first one returned is the first instance of dhillon in your file. And you'll know where to look for it.

**Edit:** opps, just saw dhillon could be a last name...
Try: "awk -F, '{ if ($2 == dhillon) print $0 }' name.txt"
or " nl name.txt | awk -F, '{ if ($3 == dhillon) print $0 }' "

**2nd Edit**
You said your data file is laid out like this:
`linenumber name name number number height`
 Is that correct? Does it look like this:
 `1 Terry Wendt 7 13 2M`
 Or like this:
 `1TerryWendt7132M` 
Or like this:
 `1,Terry,Wendt,7,13,2M`
This is why people asked for sample data when you asked the question. If I don't know how your data is actually laid out, I can't give you an accurate answer. As a simple text data file review:

1. Usually, each line is a "Record".
2. Each data element is a "Field", such as "firstname".
3. In between each field is a separator, such as a comma, space, tab, or a colon. Unless...
4. Each field is length delimited - I.E., "firstname" starts at space one, and is 26 characters in length. The next field might be "lastname", and it starts at position 27, and it's 26 characters in length...

Can you supply a couple of records(lines) of your data? Or show an accurate representation of your data? If not, no one can help you.

Comment: sorry to mention the file already has line numbers

Comment: So did this work for you?